# What exactly is "Glanzbild" in English?

Tags: word-request, translation

What are the glossy, decorative chromolithography prints cut or stamped out following the contours of the image and often enhanced by embossing called in English? They were used in poetry books, letters, as bookmarks, even on Christmas tree ornaments. Collecting them used to be very popular. What did they call them in Victorian times or in the early 20th century?  *Glanzbild* in German.

Comment: Google translate gives "Scrap pattern" but I suspect that was not the commonly used term for the thing you describe.

Comment: I doubt English has any better term than "scrap picture" - which you probably won;t find in any dictionary, but it would sometimes be used to refer to the "cuttings" that you might stick in your [***scrapbook.***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrapbook)

Comment: scraps or prints.

Answer (score 1):

*Glanzbilder* or *Reliefs, Oblaten, Albumbilder, Rosenbilder, Lackbilder, Stammbuchbilder, Kleebilder, Matritzen, Scrapbilder, Poesiebilder,* etc are usually called 'scrap pictures' in English speaking countries. A sheet of them is often called a 'scrap sheet'.

[Glanzbilder – Scrap Pictures to Collect, Trade and Decorate](https://germangirlinamerica.com/glanzbilder-scrap-pictures-to-collect-trade-and-decorate/)

[image]

Comment: It looks like some people also call them [scrap reliefs](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/kay7jay/scrap-reliefs/) or [scrap die-cuts](https://www.vintage-ornaments.com/vintage-paper-scraps-die-cuts), or [German scrap](https://www.etsy.com/market/german_scrap). Personally, I think English should just steal "Glanzbilder" :)

Comment: @ColleenV "*We don't just borrow words; on occasion, English has pursued other languages down alleyways to beat them unconscious and rifle their pockets for new vocabulary.*" - James Nicoll, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Nicoll#%22The_Purity_of_the_English_Language%22

Comment: @DavidSiegel That's one of my favorite quotes, even though the first time I saw it, it was (mis)attributed to Booker T. Washington.

Comment: @ColleenV I used to interact with Nicoll often on rec.arts.sf.written. I compared that quote with  "*It makes no sense to argue about legitimate English. English was the result of attempts by Norman men-at-arms to make dates with Saxon barmaids, and no more legitimate than any of the other results.*" from *The Other Human Race* (2nd Fuzzy novel) by H. Beam Piper.